# The command to get avatar is not working correctly (Problem with SocketGuildUser maybe)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, discord.net

A very simple command to get the user's avatar. However, it works unstable and incorrectly (example in the screenshot). Bot does not respond to all users and not every time. What can this be related to? Maybe I don't understand something, but in my opinion, there is a problem with SocketGuildUser. Here is a simplified code snippet for clarity:

```
        [Command("avatar")]
        [Alias("getavatar")]
        public async Task GetAvatar(ushort res, SocketGuildUser user = null)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(Context.User.GetAvatarUrl(size: res));
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(user.GetAvatarUrl(size: res));
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: the user probably isn't in cache...enable member intents in discord developer portal

Comment: @Anu6is your advice really helped me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anu6is I am ready to accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply enable intents in the discord developer portal. Without it, users will not be cached and your user type reader will fail to parse any mentioned users

Edit: An alternate method would be to create your own custom type reader that will fallback to making a rest request if fetching the user from cache yields no results.